# SimpleDateFormat conversion - parse error at time zone NZDT

Tags: android, date

I have following string I want to convert to date using Android:

```
Wed Mar 11 13:06:22 NZDT 2015
```

I am using following format to parse above string, but it doesn't work, as it says date is unparsable at offset 20 (time zone).

```
private static SimpleDateFormat date = new
SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

Any idea why? It works, If I set time zone to GMT, but not the other way.

Comment: this list https://gist.github.com/mtrung/a3f7caaa7e674ac7e6c4 seems to suggest that your timezone is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

As your time zone is in short form (*NZDT*) so you have to use `zzz`.
Actually `zzzz` will return full form **New Zealand Daylight Time**

So, correct format is:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat  romDateFormat = new
SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Comment: I think Daylight Saving timing is not supported here. Just for testing can you try with NZT? If it works then we can come to a conclusion that NZDT is not supported.